# adding object to nsmutablearray with custom delegate function giving error

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

i'm declaring an array in firstviewcontroller like

```
@interface ClassesList : UIViewController
{
  NSMutableArray *className;
}
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *className;
```

and defining an delegate method to add an object to array in next view controller

```
@protocol Createclass <NSObject>

-(void)addnewObject:(NSString*)string;;

@end
```

and sending string with textfiled string

```
[self.delegate addnewClass:_className.text];
```

while calling this metod in firstviewcontroller it is showing error

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector        sent to instance
```

here is my edit

```
-(void)addnewClass:(NSString *)string
{
 [className addObject:string];
 [self.table reloadData];
}
```

i'm getting an dictionary from plist file which stores a list of classes

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"classesArray.plist"];


NSDictionary *StudentDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];



NSArray *See = StudentDict[@"alldata"];

className = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

className= [See valueForKey:@"class_name"];
```

Comment: Can you post the code of -(void)addnewObject:(NSString*)string in your firstViewController

Comment: Adn yout protocol method is called addnewObject not addnewClass, so it should be [self.delegate addnewObject:_className.text];

Comment: @AntonijoDev sorry for addnewObject just changed for posting question

Comment: set a breakpoint at [className addObject:string]; and in console print object "className", it looks like that is not an array, so do: po NSStringFromClass([className class]), it should clear things up. You should name you variables more accurately, from your post I can only assume that you have UILabel className in yout second view controller and the variable NSMutableArray with the same name in your first view controller, it is confusing.

Comment: i put breakpoint and it is showing objects in mutable array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [See valueForKey:@"class_name"] contains array then that is your error cause:

```
[See valueForKey:@"class_name"];
```

returns immutable array.

Replace:

```
className = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
className= [See valueForKey:@"class_name"];
```

with:

```
className= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[See valueForKey:@"class_name"]];
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: no pob, when you earn enough rep, please accept this answer, thx

Answer (score 2):

The error message you see:

```
reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Means you have an immutable array and you are trying to mutate it (call `addObject:`), and it doesn't implement that method.

You haven't shown all of your delegate implementation but this would suggest that it is working fine and that the problem is that you have set `className` to an immutable instead of a mutable array.

---

Here:

```
className = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

className= [See valueForKey:@"class_name"];
```

You create an empty mutable array and then replace it with an immutable array (loading like that always returns immutable objects).

You should remove the first line and change the second to take a `mutableCopy` or to use the property list serialisation API which allows you to create mutable containers and leaves.

Comment: have a look my declaration of className

Comment: The declaration doesn't mean that is what it points to if you make a mistake. It could be a pointer to an NSNumber and it wouldn't cause a problem until you try to use it as a mutable array...

Comment: so how to add to my classname array any suggestions